# How can I install and run Android Screenshot Library (ASL) from my Android App?

Tags: android, service, screenshot

I need to take screenshots from a background service to follow the user experience with not rooted devices.

I thought in Android Screenshot Library (ASL) http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/ to take the screenshot but I don't know how I can install ASL and start it from the device without ADB.

I tried to use this code to install and run ASL:

```
// Install ASL
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"asl-native";
Process process = Runtime .getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/mv " +f + " /data/local/asl-native");
process = Runtime .getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/asl-native");

// Run ASL
Process process = Runtime .getRuntime().exec("/data/local/asl-native /data/local/asl-native.log" );
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not think it would work, for security reasons. But one way to work around might be to let your user switch on the adb, then do the adb over network from your own device and start the service.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the problem is ASL installation is not easy for common users and I want to offer them a easy user experience.

Comment: In readme.txt i find this
Android Screenshot Library
Native application project
**************************

This project is native part of Android Screenshot Library. It's a C code compiled into ARM executable using the variant of GCC compiler, available here:

 http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release1293

It shall be compiled with:

 {ARM-PATH}/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static main.c -o {output}
where {ARM-PATH} is the location of files from .tar.gz from the URL above.
The resulting executable is to be attached as an asset to 'native-launcher' .apk.